# macro hazards in c preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have define the following macro,

```
#define abss(a) a >= 0 ? a : -a
```

while invoking this with,

```
int b=-1;
int c = abss(b);
printf("%d\n",c);
```

it should replaced in the form b >= 0 ? b : --b, which should output -2, but it outputs in my Bloodshed/DevC++ compiler 1.

I am analyzing C language for examination purpose, so I have to know what actually happens to the above case in C. Is the output result 1 is for CPP compiler I am using or what???

Comment: You maybe read something first.... I mean about the C/C++.

Comment: And please, please **don't** read that manual you keep linking to, *ever again*. It's {vulgar term deleted} beyond bad, useless, misleading, deranged, brain-dead, the worst work I've seen on the subject in over 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

Your code

```
int b=-1;
int c = abss(b);
printf("%d\n",c);
```

gets translated by the preprocessor to:

```
int b=-1;
int c = b >= 0 ? b : -b;
printf("%d\n",c);
```

(the `int b=-1` is in the C domain whereas the `abss(b)` gets expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler gets to `int b=-1`)

Comment: check this at section 6-5 of preprocessor...http://elmicro.com/files/cosmic/clanguage.pdf

Comment: @alaminhosain: firstly, the manual is wrong. If it accurately describes what Cosmic compilers do, then the compilers are wrong. In their example it is *not* the case that `ABS(-b)` expands to `-b >= 0 ? -b : --b`, in fact it expands to `-b >= 0 ? -b : - -b`. Secondly, you didn't follow the example in the manual anyway, since you did `abss(b)` not `abss(-b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why on earth do you think it should output -2?

```
#define abss(a) a >= 0 ? a : -a
```

so this:
   int c = abss(b)

becomes
   int c = b >= 0 ? b : -b

and b is -1, so that will evaluate to 1

by the way, you should bracket every use of a macro parameter, as you may get passed such things as x + 1. which would evaluate rather strangely.

Not to mention the results of abss(++x)

Comment: I did not expect output -2. I did expect compiler to output wrong as I read in a c language manual by cosmic software...you can check this at section 6-5 of preprocessor...http://elmicro.com/files/cosmic/clanguage.pdf

Comment: There is a subtle difference between abss(b) where b = -1 and abss(-b) where b is 1. Note that you are passing 2 different text strings to the macro. What you've coded isn't at all the same thing as the example in the book. Read the explanation in the book more carefully.

Comment: also, as Steve said above, your compiler is not exactly standard if it does that as it's not meant to paste symbols in that way

Answer (score 1):

```
#define neg(a) -a

int b = -1;
neg(b);
```

In the above case, the macro is expanded to `-b` by the preprocessor, which will result in the value of 1. The preprocessor won't even be *aware* that the sign of the *content* of `b` is negative, so where should the second `-` come from to form a prefix decrement operator?

Even if you wrote it like this:

```
 neg( -b );
```

Macro replacement is done on *token* level, not as a textual search & replace. You would get the equivalent of `- ( -b )`, but *not* `--b`.

**Edit:** The manual you link to in other comments is outdated (does not even address the C99 standard), and is *dangerously* bad. Just skimming through it I found half a dozen of statements that will make you look *real stupid* if you assume them to be correct. Don't use it, other than to light a fire.

Comment: You have not answered the question - **why** is it happening. This is merely another example where the problem arises.

Comment: And actually, you get `-b`. Why is there even a discussion about `--b`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Answer expanded. It's you who is expecting the code to result in a decrement, and your assumption is false.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: ...unless, of course, you mistyped your macro.

Comment: @DevSolar: The question says: `it should replaced in the form b >= 0 ? b : --b`. Note the decrement operator. There is a typo in the question, either in the initial macro definition of the explanation of what the questioner is expecting.

Comment: @RobH: Check out the OP's comment to Luchian's answer. He's working from a FUBAR manual, and *actually* expects this behaviour...

Comment: @DevSolar: I now (a) see that I'm a dope, and intended to reply to Luchian's comment and (b) have to get myself a copy of that programming manual for a chuckle.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to, but your initial answer didn't reflect why it doesn't. It just provided a different macro which exibits the same behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sorry, confused you with the OP.

Comment: @DevSolar: Do you have a source for `Macro replacement is done [...] not as a textual search & replace` please? I thought that was precisely how preprocessor macros worked. K&R section 4.11.2 mentions `token` once but doesn't expand on that. My interest has been piqued.

Comment: @RobH: macro argument expansion is performed on a sequence of tokens (after the source is lexed), not on a sequence of characters. It is slightly more than text replacement, although it's close enough that it's often described that way. So the sequence of tokens `neg ( - b )` expands to the sequence of tokens `- - b`, not the sequence of tokens `-- b`. Read the standard if K&R doesn't cover it: part of the point of standardization was to pin this stuff down in formal language.

Comment: @RobH: I'm looking at chapter 6.10 "Preprocessing directives" of the C99 standard document, which talks about "preprocessing tokens" and "token sequences" all over. Hard to point out a single quote that directly address this current subject here, but it is pretty clear semantically. But to be honest, I was writing from experience, not chapter and verse. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your macro expands to

```
b >= 0 ? b : -b;
```

Not to `b >= 0 ? b : --(-b);` or whatever it is you expected.

Are you suggesting that

```
int x = -4;
-x;
```

should decrement `x`?

**Bottom line** - avoid macro use when possible.

Comment: I found this expansion in Cosmic Software's C language manual at 6-5 section of preprocessor, you may check this....   http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=c+language+manual+pdf+cosmic&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Felmicro.com%2Ffiles%2Fcosmic%2Fclanguage.pdf&ei=lZLpT53kFYfOsgaxsYXeDg&usg=AFQjCNEI6k3OKRLlznM-mrbB-79Q8bKv7g

Comment: @alaminhosain: Two points. First: that manual is wrong, perhaps obsolete (first C preprocessors behaved that way, but that was before ANSI standard and that's 23 years ago). Second: you reproduced the example wrong. A `-` directly in the macro argument will appear in the expansion, but `-` used in initializing a variable that will become parameter won't, because the preprocessor only works with the variable's name.

Comment: example you have given is a compile time work. but macro expanding occurs before compilation... how you can compare them??

Comment: @alaminhosain because the macro expands to exactly the same thing: `-b`.

Comment: @JanHudec can you give me a link to up-to-date manual please??? I really need it...

Comment: @alaminhosain: A quick search, or even a visit at Wikipedia, would give you a wide range of material, both on- and offline. Kernighan & Ritchie "The C Programming Language" is the seminal book on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The macro processor will never attach two adjacent tokens together, even if there is no whitespace between them, so indeed, as other posters have mentioned, your macro expands to `- b`, or `1.`

If you *want* two tokens to become one when expanded by the preprocessor, you have to use the *token pasting operator* `##`, something like

```
#define abss(a) a >= 0 ? a : - ## a
```

this will indeed do what you want, in the sense that the negative sign and the variable will form one token. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on how you look at it!) the pasted token "-b" will be invalid, and the expansion will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

This macro

```
#define abss(a) a >= 0 ? a : -a
```

is indeed hazardous, but the hazards are not where you think they are. The expression from your post

```
int c = abss(b);
```

works perfectly fine. However, consider what happens when the expression is not a simple variable, but is a function that is hard to calculate, or when it is an expression with side effects. For example

```
int c = abss(long_calc(arg1, arg2));
```

or

```
int c = abss(ask_user("Enter a value"));
```

or

```
int c = abss(b++);
```

If `abss` were a function, all three invocations would produce good results in predictable time. However, the macro makes the first call invoke `long_calc` and `ask_user` twice (what if the user enters a different number when prompted again?), and it post-increments `b` twice.

Moreover, consider this seemingly simple expression:

```
int c = abss(b) + 123;
```

Since `+` has a higher precedence than `? :`, the resulting expansion will look like this:

```
int c = b >= 0 ? b : -b + 123;
```

When `b` is positive, `123` will not be added, so the meaning of the expression will change dramatically!

This last shortcoming can be addressed by enclosing the expression in parentheses. You should also enclose in parentheses each macro argument, like this:

```
 #define abss(a) ((a) >= 0 ? (a) : -(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for you getting the behaviour is preprocessor will just replace a with b and so effectively your code after preprocessing will be like

```
b >= 0 ? b : -b
```

and not

```
b >= 0 ? b : --b
```

So, when if b = -1, then it will effectively be considered as -(-1) and thus becomes 1.

You can check the preprocessor output and see it for yourself.

Comment: I presumed that before coding that because that is a common sense about coding...but can you please check section 6-5 of preprocessor at http://elmicro.com/files/cosmic/clanguage.pdf

Comment: Section 6-5 talks about passing -b to the macro. But, in your example, you are passing b which is assigned -1. If you pass -b, then you will get the result as mentioned in the book. Hope you are getting the point.